# Converting pretty URL into GET parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After hours spent by searching with no success I would like to ask for help.

I need to (silently) rewrite this URL: `http://example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc`
into this: `http://example.com/?p1=aaa&p2=bbb&p3=ccc`

Basically I need to convert pretty URL into GET params.
My requirements are:

- user must not know about this rewriting (browser address-bar unchanged)
- working for any number of levels / arguments

Please help.

What I have now is:
`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteRule /([^/]+)/([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/? ?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4 [NC,L]`

I wanted to write "this works for maximum 4 parameters" but.... it suddenly stopped work at all and I got 500 Internal Server Error? Aaaarg! I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easier way maybe doing this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then in your code you need to just explode $_GET['params'] to get url parts. This work for any numbers of parameters you may have and user will not see the difference because url will always look like example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc

Comment: Still 500 Internal server error. Isn't this creating infinite rewrite loop ?

Comment: try now, -f line skips all files from rewrite and -d all directories

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# handle 4 parameters
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4 [QSA,L]

# handle 3 parameters
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3 [QSA,L]
```